# Java Webapp: generate File, then show in as part of JSP?

Tags: tomcat, pdf, web-applications

I want to generate jasper reports and show them in an inline-frame afterwards (jsp page).
The only way I can imagine to get this done, is to write the report to a pdf file and then reference somehow to this file.

Here is my test: it successfully generates the file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "jaspertest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView report() throws JRException, IOException {      
// TODO: compile here
//JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("path/to/myReport.jrxml");

String fileName = "/jasper/Blank_A4.jasper";
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
InputStream jasperStream = new FileInputStream(file);

ReportSource reportSource = new ReportSource(this.realestateService);

Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, reportSource);

String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File reportFile = new File(home + "/tomcat/generated/generated_report.pdf");
reportFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
if (!reportFile.exists())
    reportFile.createNewFile();

OutputStream outStream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(reportFile);

//final OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
outStream.close();
return new ModelAndView("report/test","pdf", reportFile.getName());
```

}

But I don't understand, if the jsp page can refer to the used pdf location now. Should I use another location? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that Jasper can render the report to html as well. So theres no need for the pdf anymore. The html can be injected to the jsp page.

This my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView report(@RequestParam(value = "report", required=true) String report) throws JRException, IOException {      

    String fileName = "/jasper/" + report;
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
    InputStream jasperStream = new FileInputStream(file);

    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperStream);

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, reportSource);

    Exporter exporter;
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    exporter = new HtmlExporter();
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out));

    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.exportReport();

    String result = out.toString();

    return new ModelAndView("report/test","pdf", result);
  }
```